# ffmpeg compilation in VS2005 assembly code in mathops.h doesn't compile

Tags: c++, assembly, ffmpeg

i'm trying to compile ffmpeg in my vs2005 but i'm stcuk on the following error:

libavcodec\x86/mathops.h(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ':'

the code its triyng to compile is

```
  __asm__ (
    "imull %3               \n\t"
    "shrdl %4, %%edx, %%eax \n\t"
    :"=a"(rt), "=d"(dummy)
    :"a"(a), "rm"(b), "ci"((uint8_t)shift)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is decidedly `gcc` style inline assembler, not Microsoft style.

I believe it can be replaced by:

```
 rt = ((int64_t)a * b) >> shift;
```